# Is it possible set multiple controller inputs at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

**Pre Notes**

- I'm creating a 4-player, multiplayer game.
- I have 4 identical controllers that are like USB SNES controllers.
- All the controllers work and input great.
- I want this game to work on multiple platforms, devices, etc.

**Here's the issue:**

When I start the game, the controllers are auto-mapped as follows...

- Player 1: controller 1
- Player 2: controller 2
- Player 3: controller 3
- Player 4: controller 6

I'm assuming that if I change the order the controllers are plugged in, or run this on a different computer/device, or use different controllers, etc., the input mapping will certainly not be what is auto-mapped to above.

**My Question:**

I do have a script that detects which controller is inputing.  (e.g. the JoyNum, which is how I figured out that Player 4 was controller 6)

Given that, is it possible to set Unity's default "Input Manager's" JoyNums at runtime to compensate?

My thoughts were to create a screen where everyone pushes start to join the game.  At that point, I will be able to detect all the controllers.  (E.g. which JoyNum each player is)  The last step will be re-mapping Unity's Input Manager.  Is this possible?

Thanks!

PS: I searched and found "Custom Input Manager" on Git, https://github.com/daemon3000/InputManager

However, the project doesn't build, and I have no idea how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

So, after much trial and error, I came up with a solution that works.  (Probably not the cleanest/recommended approach though)

Step 1) Add every Joystick Axis (all 28), for every controller (all 8) in your Input Manager.  (A script can make this very easy/much less time consuming)

Step 2) Create your own Input Mapper.  (Detect the "up", and "left" of every controller.)

Step 3) Save those results to the "PlayerPrefs" file.

Step 4) Create your own Input detection script.  (The only things that needs to access Unity's Input Manager are the Joystick Axis'.)  The other buttons can be done manually from the (strings) loaded from the PlayerPrefs file.

**Pros of this approach:**

- Works as a catch all.  (For any controller, device, computer, etc.)
- Is very stable!
- Allows for maximum control over all inputs and what they do.

**Cons:**

- Seems a little ridiculous to have to do all this.
- Fairly time consuming.  (But can easily be used again on future projects)
- Seems sloppy, but works great.